# How to access a local variable in a different function

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, instance, self

I have created a game of "Hangman" in which the computer chooses a random word the user has to guess the word, letter by letter.

At the end, I wanted to ask the user whether he wants to play the game again, however I cannot use the variables used in one method as their scope is limited to only one function in python.

```
class Hangman():
    def start(self):
        y = []
        blanks = []
        guessed = []
        repeat = []
        self.gamePlay = True

    def beginning(self):
        while l.gamePlay == True:
            l.start()

            ask = input('Would you like to play again(Y or N): ')
        if ask.upper() == 'Y':
        pass
        else:
            l.gamePlay = False

l = Hangman()
l.beginning()
```

I would like to know how to extend the scope of variable 'gamePlay' such that it will work even in the beginning() function.

Currently, it says: AttributeError: 'Hangman' object has no attribute 'gamePlay'.

I am just beginning to learn Python and have come up against this difficulty.

Comment: Change all `l.gamePlay` to `self.gamePlay` (actually, all `l.` to `self.`)

Comment: beginning is a member function of Hangman, which gets the instance as the "self" variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your class a lot by moving all your variables to the constructor of class, `__init__` as follows
Also note that inside any function of your class, you can access an attribute of the class `x` by doing `self.x`

```
class Hangman():

    def __init__(self):

        self.y = []
        self.blanks = []
        self.guessed = []
        self.repeat = []
        self.gameplay = True

    def beginning(self):
        while self.gameplay == True:
            ask = input('Would you like to play again(Y or N): ')
            if ask.upper() == 'Y':
                pass
            else:
                self.gameplay = False
```

Then when you run your code as follows.

```
hm = Hangman()
hm.beginning()
```

You can observe the output as follows:

```
Would you like to play again(Y or N): Y
Would you like to play again(Y or N): Y
Would you like to play again(Y or N): Y
Would you like to play again(Y or N): N
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just move the variable declaration up, like so

```
class Hangman():
    gamePlay = True
```

it becomes a member of the object as opposed to a variable local to the function. Thus, it is visible from within all its methods.